# Am I guaranteed to get a value back from a TryPop against a ConcurrentStack

Tags: c#, multithreading

i have a C# app.  There is a Stack collection that is used.

Now, this collection is being access from many threads and so I need to make it Thread-Safe.

So, I am looking at using a ConcurrentStack Collection instead.

Now this uses TryPeek, TryPop, TryPush and it returns a True/False flag to signal success or not.

Is this flag a recognition of whether an object exists or not in the collection or is it because it may fail because another Thread is accessing the collection at the same time and that I would need to re-attempt the action?

Comment: The documentation states that `false` is returned when the collection doesn't have an item to remove and return.

Comment: @amy thanks for that confirmation

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're trying to ask here. But just in case you're uncertain - you've already stated that this is multithreaded access. Any *reasoning* you perform about any return values is *irrelevant* to what the state of the collection will be the next time you attempt to access it.

Comment: all it does is look at head item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the source code (as decompiled by ILSpy) for `ConcurrentStack.TryPop<T>()`:

```
public bool TryPop(out T result)
{
    ConcurrentStack<T>.Node head = this.m_head;
    if (head == null)
    {
        result = default(T);
        return false;
    }
    if (Interlocked.CompareExchange<ConcurrentStack<T>.Node>(ref this.m_head, head.m_next, head) == head)
    {
        result = head.m_value;
        return true;
    }
    return this.TryPopCore(out result);
}
```

This method returns `false` when the item can't be removed/returned, or when `TryPopCore` returns `false`.  So here is that:

```
private bool TryPopCore(out T result)
{
    ConcurrentStack<T>.Node node;
    if (this.TryPopCore(1, out node) == 1)
    {
        result = node.m_value;
        return true;
    }
    result = default(T);
    return false;
}
```

So that returns whether `TryPopCore(int, out ConcurrentStack<T>.Node)` is successful:

```
private int TryPopCore(int count, out ConcurrentStack<T>.Node poppedHead)
{
    SpinWait spinWait = default(SpinWait);
    int num = 1;
    Random random = new Random(Environment.TickCount & 2147483647);
    ConcurrentStack<T>.Node head;
    int num2;
    while (true)
    {
        head = this.m_head;
        if (head == null)
        {
            break;
        }
        ConcurrentStack<T>.Node node = head;
        num2 = 1;
        while (num2 < count && node.m_next != null)
        {
            node = node.m_next;
            num2++;
        }
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange<ConcurrentStack<T>.Node>(ref this.m_head, node.m_next, head) == head)
        {
            goto Block_5;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            spinWait.SpinOnce();
        }
        num = (spinWait.NextSpinWillYield ? random.Next(1, 8) : (num * 2));
    }
    if (count == 1 && CDSCollectionETWBCLProvider.Log.IsEnabled())
    {
        CDSCollectionETWBCLProvider.Log.ConcurrentStack_FastPopFailed(spinWait.Count);
    }
    poppedHead = null;
    return 0;
    Block_5:
    if (count == 1 && CDSCollectionETWBCLProvider.Log.IsEnabled())
    {
        CDSCollectionETWBCLProvider.Log.ConcurrentStack_FastPopFailed(spinWait.Count);
    }
    poppedHead = head;
    return num2;
}
```

As you can see, it returns false if it can't remove an item and then return it.  There's a lot to this last function, and the decompiled code isn't the cleanest, but it does appear to conform to what the documentation states.

Comment: Thanks.  i am rushing from work now and will look at this when back. thanks again.